# A priority queue for functions in C

Tags: c, function-pointers, priority-queue

I'd like a priority queue that executes a function instead of returns an object when we pop it - but I want the function pointer and arguments to be set when I push the functions. What's the best way of accomplishing this?

I came up with

```
struct onpop {
    int priority;
    void (*do_on_pop)(char** args);
    char** args;
    struct onpop* next;
};
```

where the linked list pointer would allow for pretty complicated chaining using basic building blocks. In this specific application, the priorities are actually of type `struct timeval` and the queue acts as a timer. Are there better ways that I have overlooked?

Comment: Why are you trying to make this the priority queue's job? Why not just pop the record and perform the call specified by the record in the code that uses the queue?

Comment: Looks about right. One think, you want the args to be of type "void". So `void **args;` or `void *args;`

Comment: @user2357112 Do you mean like ret=pop(pq); do_on_pop(ret.args)? Because I want to be able to overwrite the function pointer with all kinds of different functions.

Comment: @Ostrich Ah, and then cast appropriately inside *do_on_pop()?

Comment: @can-i-bus, yeap. Each function should know what it is expecting and what it should cast to.

Comment: @can-i-bus: `ret.do_on_pop(ret.args)`

Comment: @user2357112 Well yeah is there any other way?

Comment: @user2357112 Oh you mean not rewriting the pop function. Sure, a separate pop_and_do() function is probably best.

Comment: I prefer to use a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) for this; specifically, a min-heap stored in an array with the timespec fields as the key. If you need cancellation, I'd use a parallel array with slots, linked to the heap entries, links updated when heap entries are moved.